# Transferring .iso from Android TCL SMARTPHONE to Debian 12 standard laptop so as to use dd to create new live USB?

Tags: android, terminal, debian, usb

I downloaded the standard, most popular Debian 12 edition, the standard -- the goto Debian distributor. But it doesn't come with a GUI OR WINDOW'S manager. How do I use the terminal to transfer a new .iso from my Android TCL SMARTPHONE to my Debian 12 standard machine on my laptop? I have no internet access on my laptop and only have a cell phone with limited access, USB, and my ThinkBook laptop.

My standard DEBIAN 12 machine certainly recognized my TCL device, though primitive I use it in prison ATM for the internet because I want to learn how to use computers. I plan on transferring the .iso to the main user's Home folder and then using the `dd` command to create a new KDE live ISO.

Comment: Cross-posted to Unix.SE: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/748868/90391